# Dual 96kHz custom Microphone Recording

Tags: raspbian, audio, usb-audio

I'm working on a project that involves two custom analog microphones, each with a -2 to +2 volt analog output signal. My goal is to capture audio from these mics using a Raspberry Pi at a minimum sampling rate of 96 kHz. However, I'm facing a challenge in finding a suitable audio capture solution that's not larger than the Raspberry Pi itself.
Here's what I've explored so far, and the issues I've encountered:

- Small USB Sound Cards, many options are available, but most seem to be limited to 48 kHz recording
- Custom Raspberry Pi HAT with a TLV320 IC, this seems like it could be a viable solution. However, I'm concerned about the complexity of creating the necessary driver
- Cmedia Chip (e.g., CM6642), this chip appears to be a good fit, but seams like they are currently unable to source

I've also considered using a small USB oscilloscope, but haven't found one that can be directly connected to the Raspberry Pi and meets this specifications. Is there a particular hat I can use or an option I'm not seeing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the [Audio Injector](https://www.audioinjector.net/) sound cards, which all support audio input.

The [Audio Injector Pro soundcard](https://www.audioinjector.net/pro-soundcard) is a similar size to a Pi and has example schematics for custom preamplifiers, such as [this RCA preamplifier](https://github.com/Audio-Injector/RCA.preamplifier.AI-ABSv1) or [XLR preamplifier](https://github.com/Audio-Injector/XLR.preamplifier.AI-ABSv1) which would suit your needs and can be modified in KiCaD if you need their input buffers to be different. If your microphones don't require input buffers then you can hack them on directly to the Pro soundcard itself.

Another option is the [Audio Injector Ultra soundcard](https://www.audioinjector.net/rpi-ultra) which has two inbuilt microphones on the preamplifier board, however you can go in through the direct stereo input without microphone gain if you prefer.

Finally the [Audio Injector zero soundcard](https://www.audioinjector.net/rpi-zero) and the [Audio Injector stereo soundcard](https://www.audioinjector.net/rpi-hat) are budget options for 96 kHz input.